# how can i traverse all cell of grid view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, gridview

i have grid view on my aspx page and i have text box above of my grid view if user type a data that is in my table it filter grid-view. i want to traverse in each cell of my grid and check the value if it is same show it, if not hide it. now i have a code that it can do this work just by one column and it traverse all row in one column. i  want change this code that i  can traverse all column and all row of it . if any body knows how please help me

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            //
            // Client Side Search (Autocomplete)
            // Get the search Key from the TextBox
            // Iterate through the 1st Column.
            // td:nth-child(1) - Filters only the 1st Column
            // If there is a match show the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]
            // Else hide the row [$(this).parent() gives the Row]

            $('#filter').keyup(function (event) {
                var searchKey = $(this).val();
                var a = $('#gvwHuman_ctl00');
                var b = a.attr.length;

              $("#gvwHuman_ctl00 tr td:nth-child("2")").each(function () {
                    var cellText = $(this).text();
                    if (cellText.indexOf(searchKey) >= 0) {
                        $(this).parent().show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                    }

                });

            });
        });
```

and its my table structure i use rad grid Telerik component but its same as grid view

```
 <table id="gvwHuman_ctl00" class="rgMasterTable rgClipCells" border="0" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;empty-cells:show;">
    <colgroup>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th class="rgResizeCol rgHeader" scope="col"> </th>
    <th class="rgHeader" scope="col" title="Drag to group or reorder" style="cursor: move;">کد</th>
    <th class="rgHeader" scope="col">
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvwHuman$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl00','')" title="Click here to sort">نام</a>
    </th>
    <th class="rgHeader" scope="col">
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvwHuman$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl01','')" title="Click here to sort">هزینه</a>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="rgFilterRow" style="font-family: Tahoma; display: none;">
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr class="rgPager" valign="middle" style="font-family: Tahoma;">
    <td colspan="4">
    <table border="0" style="width:100%;border-spacing:0;" summary="Data pager which controls on which page is the RadGrid control.">
    <caption>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="rgPagerCell NextPrevAndNumeric">
    <div class="rgWrap rgArrPart1">
    <div class="rgWrap rgNumPart">
    <div class="rgWrap rgArrPart2">
    <div class="rgWrap rgAdvPart">
    <span id="gvwHuman_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeLabel" class="rgPagerLabel">سایز صفحه</span>
    <div id="gvwHuman_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageSizeComboBox" class="RadComboBox RadComboBox_WebBlue RadComboBox_rtl RadComboBox_WebBlue_rtl" style="width:46px;">
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: just remove `:nth-child("2")` and it shall be called for every row and every cell in grid.

Comment: i do this work but it just filter my last column of grid view  not all of them

Comment: no body knows more than this?

Comment: can you show your table structure please.

Comment: i add it in my question

Comment: You shared your grid source code, please share client output/html table that is being rendered, cause jquery shall work on it only.

Comment: i edit it but it has many code if you want all code say me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30614/discussion-between-furqan-and-sara-sodagari)

Comment: if any body knows about my problem and have solution for it say me